# Splitting a blog body content into different sectors in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, blogs

I'm trying to split the contents of my blog into different sections. I don't know what logic to use so that I can't have an image between text sections. I don't want to create a foreign key for the body as my models would get very complex and messy. I don't can't copy my code here because I am asking this question with my mobile phone. I hope you understand my question...

I haven't tried anything yet so I will appreciate any idea.

Comment: The [template guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/) of django will guide you through this journey. It's telling you how to pass variables from the back end to dedicated spaces in your template. Without code it is impossible to help you better.